# Webform field options missing Entity Reference?

Tags: 7, entities, webforms

We're using Webform 3.27 in Drupal 7 (not my call, don't yell at me) and it looks like one of the field type options should be Entity Reference, but we don't have that option. Not sure what's going on there.

Ultimately what I'm trying to do is add an Entity Reference select field that, when an option is selected, will populate up to four other existing fields (like [Entity Reference Autofill](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_autofill) works in a Content Type). Is that even possible using Webform?

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but no. We already have that module. What I need is something like [Entity reference autofill](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_autofill). That module does exactly what I want, but only for Content Types.

Comment: We have a form with a select field that's populated from a content type. There are also four related text fields.

When a user selects an option from the select field, we need to automatically fill in the four text fields with the associated values based on that selection. We can't do it behind-the-scenes because the user needs to see and be able to edit those values if necessary.

We could use the Content Type input form as a block, but the form would be better as a multi-page Webform. We also have other forms that would benefit from that feature.

Answer (score 2):

This module might do what you want, [webform references](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_references).

From description,

> Provides a webform component that can reference a node/term/user in webform. It provides "Select List", "Autocomplete", "Checkbox" and "Radio" as widget.
>   A view with entityreference display can also be used to get the list as options.